# jquery ajax delete not delete in db

Tags: jquery, mysql, pdo

I have this script in jquery-ajax to delete a row in table, but don't delete in db nothing...only delete the row in the table in the page...maybe you can't help me with this..
I tried with two form because the id in the table paciente is id_paciente...so I tried with this form:
here is the **ajax script**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('table#delTable td a.btn-danger').click(function()
        {
            if (confirm("Realmente desea borrar el registro del paciente?"))
            {
                var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
                var data = '?id_paciente=' + id ;
                var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

                $.ajax(
                {
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "delete.php",
                       data: data,
                       cache: false,

                       success: function()
                       {
                            parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                       }
                 });                
            }
        });

        // style the table with alternate colors
        // sets specified color for every odd row
        $('table#delTable tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
    });

</script>
```

**and with this too:**

```
code.....
var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
var data = 'id=' + id ;
var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
.....code
```

This is the **button**:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" id="<?php echo $row['id_paciente']; ?>" href="#" >
<i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
Borrar
</a>
```

here is **delete.php**

```
<?php 
include_once("config.php");

$count=$conn->prepare("delete from PACIENTES WHERE id_paciente=:id_paciente");
$count->bindParam(":id_paciente",$id_paciente,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$count->execute();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not getting the id from the  tag. You are trying to get it from the .

Try changing `var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');` to `var id = $(this).attr('id');`

**Updated after finally figuring out the problem.**

Comment: I need to remove the user from the table and from the db

Comment: Is the ajax request being triggered? Is the id variable being received in php? I think the id is not making it to php correctly. In the second part of your example you have: `var data = 'id=' + id ;` try `var data = 'id_paciente=' + id ;`. Also in the PHP I don't see you getting the id from the request. `$_POST["id_paciente"]`.

Comment: mm I have this into the button `id="<?php echo $row['id_paciente']; ?>"`...I think the id variable is receive in php, but I not know if work... I tried with `var data = 'id_paciente=' + id ;` and with `var data = '?id_paciente=' + id ;` but don't delete it in db... I have this another **delete.php**  `<?php
include("config.php");
if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];

$query = "delete from PACIENTES where id_paciente='$id'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
}
?>`  and not work too...

Comment: add some logging or an echo to delete.php to see if the id is making it to php.

Comment: work if I insert in href the url `href=delete.php`, but the button send me to delete.php page...I don't want to go to delete.php only for delete a user in db..I think the ajax is not making the request or catch the id properly...I will need to find another ajax script maybe... thank you for your support @Lance Hudson

Comment: can you run something like http://fiddler2.com/ ? It will tell you if the ajax request is being made and let you see the differences between when you do it manually and through ajax.

Comment: well the ajax is not get the id...this is the textview in findler  id_paciente=undefined thank you @Lance Hudson

Comment: ok, i think this is it then. `var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');` should be `var id = $(this).attr('id');` because the id is on the a tag.

Comment: Wow!! now it works!! I only change id to id_paciente and insert your suggest and works! thank you for your great support @Lance Hudson   best regards!